# change background position onclick

Tags: html, css

I have an anchor `<a>`, which I am using as a button.
I am using a sprite to make the button change its shape depending on mouse events.
From normal to hover, It is working. I change the opacity as indicated in code below.
The problem is when the button is clicked (from hover to click). I want the background position to slide from 46% to 51% to show another part of the sprite.
I tried `before`, `after`, `focus`...but in vain. Your help is appreeciated.

```
.left_arrow_trigger
{
    height:100%; 
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    background: url('../images/dashboard_sprite.png') no-repeat;
    background-position:0 46%; 
    background-size: 1500% 1700%;
    opacity:.41;

}

.left_arrow_trigger:hover
{
    opacity:.90;
}

.left_arrow_trigger:focus 
{
background-position:0 51%; 

}
```

Comment: Could you use jquery?

Comment: Is there a problem with using javascript?

Comment: Does it mean: there is no solution in CSS? I am using jQuery.

Comment: Click events need JS/JQ. You could use `:active` but that will only work while the mouse button is held down.

Comment: Thank you all, for your help. `:active` is doing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
.left_arrow_trigger:active 
{
  background-position:0 51%; 
}
```